# Stumped: for loop to build an array not working, initial condition ignored?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, initialization

This one has me stumped. Here is my code to build an array, b[i] of doubles, from 0 to N where N = 126.

```
int N = 126;
double b[N];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < N; i++);
{
    b[i] = (double)i;
    printf("b[%lf] = %d\n",b[i], i);
}
```

For some reason, this is what I get:

```
b[126.000000] = 126
```

and nothing else. The initial condition of i being at 0 is ignored, and for some reason it sets i to be the value of N. Strange!

I'm a bit of a c novice so I must be missing something obvious. Any help greatly appreciated!

Andy.

Comment: Typo, remove `;` from `for(i = 0; i < N; i++);`

Comment: Voting to close as typo. Also, crank up your compiler's warning levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is at you using the `;` at the end of the `for loop` statement. That is why the program is simply executing the remaining statements as if they are in no loop, and at that time `i` has become 126.

Comment: That's fixed it! I'm so doofy. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **`;`** on the end of the for loop, it is running through the loop without doing anything then executing the body for the last value of `i`(which is N = 126)